# Div not shrinking from right side when resizing

Tags: css

My div is unable to shrink from the right side not sure why as it's working fine from the left side, Why could this be happening?

*Code Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-williams-p3tl71?resolutionWidth=750&resolutionHeight=675&file=/src/App.js*

Main Container CSS

```
    .post {
          background-color: #ffffff;
         
          align-items: center;
          align-self: center;
          align-content: center;
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.493);
          border-width: 0.5px;
          stroke-linejoin: miter;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use media query or vw (viewport width)